# Where is the SVN config file on google code?

Tags: svn, location, config, google-code

I have a little problem showing html file as documentation on my google code page.

I need to know where the SVN config file is on google code.

I tried to upload a file called 'config' into the root directory of the SVN and into the /.subversion/ directory but it's not being applied, or at least the HTML pages just show as plain text when clicking 'raw file'.

I read this:
http://manjeetdahiya.com/2010/09/29/serving-html-documentation-from-google-code-svn/

but don't really know where the config file is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided the **SVN client config** is meant. You didn't specify your OS and SVN client, but  I can say, that on Linux this is located in your home directory, there should be a directory called .subversion which contains the client configuration file. On Windows check the directory where the client program is installed.

Comment: ah i wanted to display HTML files with thhe raw file viewer from a browser, is that possible? : O Then I misunderstood the article. I thought it's for google code page.

Comment: Well, in this case, according to the article you can set the SVN property for particular file and Google Code should render this correspondingly. You can set this property with "svn propset svn:mime-type "text/html" file.html ". Check this http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/svn/svn.advanced.props.html